# Notification "Backup your files" not aware that other backup program was used

Tags: windows-7, backup, notifications, acronis-trueimage

I backed up a computer using Acronis True Image but Windows keeps popping up "Backup your files" and if I click the balloon the built in Windows Backup tool starts backing up. How can I disable this or preferably make it sync with Acronis? I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable it, open Action Center, click "Change Action Center settings" (left hand side of the window) and then uncheck the "Windows Backup" checkbox and then OK.

Judging by the fact that it is labeled specifically *Windows* Backup, its APIs are probably not exposed to 3d party programs the way spyware protection is (and which is generically called "Spyware and related protection" rather than "Windows Defender").